# Add "swipe-like" mouse events

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, slideshow

I have a problem with a new magento theme I'm creating from RWD base. In my page I have a lot of small sliders showing the products.
all of these sliders are using the slideshow.js provided from magento and it slide really well in desktop (mouseclick on prev/next button) and in mobile (swipe left and right).
The problem is because I have to implement the swipe left and right on the desktop view.
This is the simple jquery function I'm using right now

```
 $j('.slideshow-container1 .slideshow1')
        .cycle({
            slides: '> li',
            pager: '.slideshow-pager',
            pagerTemplate: '<span class="pager-box"></span>',
            speed: 600,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            swipe: true,
            prev: '.slideshow-prev1',
            next: '.slideshow-next1',
            fx: 'scrollHorz'
        }).cycle('pause');
```

Comment: You should look at the plugin and see how it's implemented there. Provide link to the plugin website and other info.

Comment: I don't think it's a plugin. Or if it is is well covered inside magento rwd core theme

Comment: I've found the plugin. Unfortunately the version inside magento is minified but i can always overwrite with a new one.
I don't see something related to the mouse swipe inside the api

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/

Comment: i look at the plugin but i don't find anything that prevent the swipe on the desktop. you have a touchscreen? or you are trying to swipe with the mouse?